# Does the rotational energy change at different points on a sphere?

Tags: energy, kinematics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I know that the linear velocity of a point on the surface of a sphere increases as it goes towards the equator. Therefore, I believe that the rotational energy increases as the position, on the surface of the sphere, goes towards the equator.

Is this an accurate statement?

And if so, then does that change in rotational energy happen because of a change in moment of inertia at specific points on a sphere or is it due to something else?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. You ask *is true that the moment of inertia of a sphere changes when your position on the surface sphere moves away from the equator* but this doesn't make sense. The moment of inertia of a sphere is a property of the sphere as a whole.

Comment: Can I know the reasons behind your statements?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. The reason why I believe that the rotational energy increases as the position moves closer to the equator is because the linear velocity increases as the position moves closer to the equator. Thus, I believe that there is an increase in rotational energy at that position relative to positions farther away from the equator. I have a significant feeling that my thought process is really wrong here.

Comment: @bobingbobs The energy of _what_?  Think about how we define energy for rotating bodies and moving bodies.  You don't look at a single point on the body; you look at the entire object.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your helpful answers! Sorry for the poorly worded question.

Answer (score 1):

Linear energy and rotational energy are not concepts for a particle, but rather for a rigid body. Linear energy is the kinetic energy of the body referred as if it was a point particle moving at the velocity of the center of mass. Rotational energy is the energy associated to its rotational inertia.

Comment: When using linear energy you can treat the objects as particles.  Orientation doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The rotational energy of a man standing on the Earth won't change due to angular velocity because the Earth has essentially a constant angular velocity. The only way that energy could change is therefore the result of the moment of inertia, but moment of inertia I is defined as the ratio of the net angular momentum L of a system to its angular velocity ω around a principal axis. Again we know the angular velocity would be constant. The moment of inertia applies to the whole sphere, not to a point on the sphere. Hence no change in rotational energy of the man on earth system.

To answer your question in the title, I would say, no.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a sphere when a shell will do (since we only care about the  surface). Any point (or element of tiny mass $m$) at latitude $\phi$ has a moment of inertia:

$$ I = m\rho^2,$$

$$ I = m R^2\cos^2{\phi},$$

where $\rho$ is the distance from the axis and $R$ is the radius of the whatever.

As pointed out by @Mtec, this element has kinetic energy, which contributes to rigid body's rotational energy:

$$ K = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 ,$$
$$ K = \frac{q}{2}m(\omega \rho)^2,$$
$$ K = \frac{1}{2}m(\omega R \cos{\phi})^2,$$
$$ K = \frac{1}{2}I\omega^2.$$

So the $\rho^2$ in the translational kinetic energy's squared velocity exactly matches the $\rho^2$ in the definition of moment of inertia, and it all works out so that the answer to your question is yes: objects (points, elements of mass, whatever) near the equator have higher kinetic energy ($\propto \cos^2{\phi}$), and they also contribute more to the moment of inertia (also $\propto \cos^2{\phi}$).